# SVG transform bug in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

https://jsfiddle.net/68uehzmu/

I have a svg composed of two paths:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<symbol id="close" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>Close</title>
<path class="close_leftarrow" d="M15.422 16.078l-1.406 1.406-6-6 6-6 1.406 1.406-4.594 4.594z"></path>
<path class="close_rightarrow" d="M9.984 6l6 6-6 6-1.406-1.406 4.594-4.594-4.594-4.594z"></path>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.close_leftarrow {
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px,.5px);
    -moz-transform: translate(3px,.5px);
    -o-transform: translate(3px,.5px);
    -ms-transform: translate(3px,.5px);
    transform: translate(3px,.5px);
}
.close_rightarrow {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-2px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-2px);
    -o-transform: translateX(-2px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-2px);
    transform: translateX(-2px);
}
```

I have a reference to it in the document:

```
<svg class="close"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#close"></use></svg>
```

I am having a problem with Internet Explorer and Edge, where the transforms are not being applied.

Is this a bug? How can I avoid it?

Comment: fwiw, all versions of IE have problems with transform and translate but Edge should not.

Comment: As of now, no versions of IE will let you apply CSS `transform` to SVG elements.